# how to merge two sound object to one sound object?? (air for android)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, air-android

I have a sound object witch i recorded from microphone.
I want to add it right before an other sound , what is your strategy??

I think it is related to byteArrays , if we add byteArray of two sound in one bytearray i think the problem will be solved.

Comment: Have you tried concatenating the byteArrays?

Comment: No. I have no idea. Can you help me about it?